# Flutter circle file image with clip oval

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to clip an image that I extracted from the image picker plugin and it does not work with `BoxDecoration.circle` , so I want to clip it as circle with oval clipper. How to achive it ?

Comment: Why don't you use CircleAvatar widget?

Comment: @VinothKumar , because my image is coming out of the Image picker plugin with the type of File so " The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'. "

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use ***`CircleAvatar`*** widget to display the obtained image to make it `circular`.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: new MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  File _image;

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: _image == null
            ? new Text('No image selected.')
            : new CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: new FileImage(_image), radius: 200.0,),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getImage,
        tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [ClipOval](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipOval-class.html) to circle the image. Just wrap your file image with `ClipOval`.

```
ClipOval(
  child: FileImage(_image)
),
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make use of BoxDecoration.Circle, this is what you need to do

```
                 Container(
                    width: 120.0,
                    height: 120.0,
                    decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            image:  FileImage(_image)
                          )
                        )
                      ),
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

I have figured it out, this a class that I will use later for clipping it's child

```
class CircleRevealClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {   CircleRevealClipper();

  @override   Rect getClip(Size size) {
    final epicenter = new Offset(size.width, size.height);

    // Calculate distance from epicenter to the top left corner to make sure clip the image into circle.

    final distanceToCorner = epicenter.dy;

    final radius = distanceToCorner;
    final diameter = radius;

    return new Rect.fromLTWH(
        epicenter.dx - radius, epicenter.dy - radius, diameter, diameter);   }

  @override   bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) {
    return true;   } }
```

Comment: Why use such a long method while there are implemented methods already? Or there's more control in your method?

Comment: This works nicely. But the circle was not centered for me. I divided the left parameter of the fromLTWH function like so: 
return Rect.fromLTWH(
        (epicenter.dx - radius) / 2, epicenter.dy - radius, diameter, diameter);
Now it is centered.